# embed python environment in c++ application

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, python-3.6, cpython

Using the c-python api I try to embed python 3.6 into a c++ application.
However instead of using the system install i'd like to use a virtual environment.
I didn't find any documentation on the way to do that.
Some related documentation mention

```
py_SetProgramName
```

or

```
py_SetPythonHome
```

Also when reading c-python code i can see the use of  `pvenv.cfg` or `._pth` files, but none of these solution seem to work.

Any idea what's the right way to use virtual environment from c api?

EDIT

Let's take a concrete example. I have python installed in

```
c:\python36
```

For my c++ application I created a virtual env using the command `python -m venv c:\my_cpp_app\python_venv\` in:

```
c:\my_cpp_app\python_venv\
```

Using the c-python api I'd like to make my cpp application use the virtual environment located in `python_venv` instead of `c:\python36\`

Comment: I assume "another virtual environment" means some special  `PYTHONHOME`/`PYTHONPATH` (https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME)  and not a completely different Python-version (which can be only choosen at compile time), in this case you have to set them prior to calling the resulting exe. Or set it in the exe using `Py_SetPath` (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetPath) / `Py_SetPythonHome`  (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetPythonHome). It is unclear what you want to do and what is your exact problem.

Comment: thx for the answer, i updated the question to add an example. Hope it will be clearer... Also i found this issue in bug python bug tracker https://bugs.python.org/issue22213 i think it's same issue.

Comment: You can try use https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Given the description in the bug report it is a not yet resolved issue (and with proposed workarounds only for linux). I don't know what you do with the embeded Python, but probably just setting the right python-path after initialization of the interpreter could be enough.

Comment: creating the environment with virtualenv instead of venv and using `Py_SetPythome` worked fine. It looks that the pep proposal was implement in 3.8. Thx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, embedded python 3.6 and virtual environment created with venv seem incompatible ([bugs.python.org/issue22213](https://bugs.python.org/issue22213))

I managed to make it work using `virtualenv` instead and by calling `Py_SetPythonHome` prior `Py_Initialize`. 
See more details on the [python startup sequence](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0432/#id42)

> **Locating Python and the standard library**
>
> The location of the Python
>   binary and the standard library is influenced by several elements. The
>   algorithm used to perform the calculation is not documented anywhere
>   other than in the source code. Even that description is
>   incomplete, as it failed to be updated for the virtual environment
>   support added in Python 3.3 (detailed in PEP 405).
>
> These calculations
>   are affected by the following function calls (made prior to calling
>   Py_Initialize()) and environment variables:
>
> - `Py_SetPythonHome()`
> - `Py_SetProgramName()`
> - `PYTHONHOME`
>
> The filesystem is also inspected for
>   pyvenv.cfg files (see PEP 405) or, failing that, a `lib/os.py` (Windows)
>   or `lib/python$VERSION/os.py` file.
>
> The build time settings for `PREFIX`
>   and `EXEC_PREFIX` are also relevant, as are some registry settings on
>   Windows. The hardcoded fallbacks are based on the layout of the
>   CPython source tree and build output when working in a source
>   checkout.

The implementation of [pep 587](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0587/) in later versions should facilitate all this!

Comment: it seems python directory should be set in system path, or theses functions cannot work, which will cause error like "cannot find the python3x.dll"